# Swagger application is now clientCredentials

Tags: authentication, swagger, swagger-2.0

Using swagger 2 in NetCore code, I do not understand how to use application flow (using client-id and client-secret)

In the official doc (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) I found this:

> OAuth 2 flows were renamed to match the OAuth 2 Specification:
>   accessCode is now authorizationCode, and application is now
>   clientCredentials.

But it does not work

```
// Activate swagger json file generation
services.AddSwaggerGen(
    options =>
    {
        var scheme = new OAuth2Scheme
        {
            Type = "oauth2",
            Flow = "clientCredentials",
            AuthorizationUrl = "https://fs.xxx.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize",
            TokenUrl = "https://fs.xxx.com/adfs/oauth2/token",
        };
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", scheme);

        options.AddSecurityRequirement(new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { "oauth2", Array.Empty<string>() }
        });
```

I do not understand... Is this doc up to date?

Comment: Ok, it looks the documentation was wrong... By using the 'previous' version: **application** it is working. (pfff I'm no longer accepted to answer from this account...?)

Comment: Thank you very much @Helen, how can I mark this ticket as solved?

Comment: You can [mark answers as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/131247) by ticking the check box next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked to is for OpenAPI 3.0, however you are using Swashbuckle which uses OpenAPI 2.0. The OpenAPI 2.0 Specification for security definitions is here:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-scheme-object

That's why the code expects OAuth flow names used in OpenAPI 2.0 (in this case, `application`) rather than those used in OpenAPI 3.0 (`clientCredentials`).